# Which model to use that can distinguish between names with the same words?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, nlp, transformer, semantic-similarity

For my task, I need a model that can distinguish between job titles that contain the same words. BERT model "msmarco-MiniLM-L-12-v3" shows high cosine similarity for positions: "Data customer" and "Data provider". The meaning of these two positions are very different and I need my model to show a low cosine similarity for these two positions.

However, in this case cosine similarity must be high: "Data customer" "Data consumer".

Which model should I use? Should I train classifier instead of nlu model? Why ChatGPT understands the difference between those texts, but BERT based models show high cosine similarity?

Answer (score 0):

Using the hosted inference here: https://huggingface.co/sentence-transformers/msmarco-MiniLM-L-12-v3 I'm getting a sentence similarity of 0.58 between data customer and data provider, and 0.86 between data customer and data consumer, which seems pretty reasonable to me.
[image]

If you're willing to train the model from scratch you could consider negative sampling https://www.baeldung.com/cs/nlps-word2vec-negative-sampling.

Using a classifier algorithm (SVMs or k-Nearest Neighbors) for a finite number of job titles would probably be a reasonable starting point, and you could use your embeddings as a starting point. hth.